# How to declare a “deferred” assignment of a value?

Tags: javascript, promise, dom-events, es6-promise

**In short:**

Let `a` and `b` be some objects, and let `p` be a property of `b`. This property may exist right now or it may appear later as a result of some event. I am looking for a way to make the assignment `a.p = b.p` to “wait” for `b.p` is ready.

**In details:**

Let `o` be an object:

```
const o = {};
```

In the real script I am working on, `o` is a custom object with many properties, but they nave no reference to the current question, so let `o` be empty.

In the same scope, a new `link` element is created to dynamically attach a stylesheet to current document:

```
const link = document.createElement('link');
Object.entries({rel: 'stylesheet', type: 'text/css', href: '/style.css'})
      .forEach(([name, value]) => link.setAttribute(name, value));
document.head.appendChild(link);
```

After this, I want `o` to have `sheet` property pointing to `link.sheet`, i.e. something like this:

```
o.sheet = link.sheet; // not working
```

It doesn’t work because `link.sheet` is created only after `link.onload` event fires. I can create a handler for this event:

```
link.addEventListener('load', function() {
  return this.sheet;
});
```

But for the sake of code purity, this function should not have access to `o`, so I don’t want to write `o.sheet = this.sheet` inside function’s body, or pass `o` to it as an argument etc. I want to create `o.sheet` and to assign the result to it outside of this handler.

So I suppose the assignment should be not `o.sheet = link.sheet`, but `o.sheet = something_else`, where `something_else` is what I don’t know yet. Maybe a promise, or special getter, or what?

Comment: How do you want to be informed that o.sheet has received a value? Or not?

Comment: @trincot, ideally, I want my script to “stop” here and “wait” until `link.stylesheet` is ready, then to assign it to `o.sheet` and to move further.

Comment: You want the script execution to really stop? That will be an awful experience for the user. The best way is not to stop, but use some callback system (and with extension, that could be a promise). But then the assignment takes place in that callback, which *seems* like something you don't like?

Comment: @trincot, my script needs the stylesheet to go further, so it has to stop and wait for it anyway.

Comment: @ Displayname: @trincot's right that you don't *really* want the script engine to stop there, because it locks up the browser. You just need everything that needs to wait for the sheet to be in a callback (the event callback if you want coupled, something else triggered by that if you want it decoupled), so it runs when the sheet is available.

Comment: @Displayname, try perusing [jQuery.Callbacks](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Callbacks/), which will give you a certain mind-set that you might find profitable, even if you don't opt for jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this with `sheet` getter:

```
Object.defineProperty(o, 'sheet', {
  get() {
    return link.sheet
  }
})
```

So until stylesheet is loaded `o.sheet` will be `null` and correct object later.

Here is a simple demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/QkPf9zHEkWaIlfUA5usZ?p=preview

Comment: FYI - The OP's clarified their question now (in comments), this answer no longer applies.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, promises are a useful decoupling mechanism. In this case, the code creating the link would return a promise which would be resolved from the link's load event handler:

```
function loadSheet() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const link = document.createElement('link');
        Object.entries({rel: 'stylesheet', type: 'text/css', href: '/style.css'})
              .forEach(([name, value]) => link.setAttribute(name, value));
        document.head.appendChild(link);
        link.addEventListener('load', () => {
            resolve(link.sheet);
        });
        link.addEventListener('error', () => {
            reject();
        });
    });
}
```

And the code consuming it:

```
loadSheet().then(sheet => {
    o.sheet = sheet;
    // Remainder of the code that needed to wait for `sheet` goes here...
});
```

Comment: *(Doh! Editing error: If you see a bunch of unformatted code after the first paragraph above, please hit refresh.)*

Comment: OP wrote *"...I don’t want to write `o.sheet = this.sheet` inside function’s body..."*. This does not seem to circumvent that (except for the lack of `this`).

Comment: @trincot: You've left the important bit off the beginning of that quote: *"But for the sake of code purity, this function should not have access to `o`..."* With the above, it doesn't.

Comment: I'd go as far as `o.sheet = loadSheet()` and make "*this property [that] may exist right now or it may appear later as a result of some event*" a promise itself.

Answer (score 1):

**Wrapper function?**

```
var loadSheet = function (cb){
    const link = document.createElement('link');
    Object.entries({rel: 'stylesheet', type: 'text/css', href: '/style.css'})
          .forEach(([name, value]) => link.setAttribute(name, value));
    document.head.appendChild(link);

    link.addEventListener('load', function() {
        cb(sheet);
    });
}


// then use like so
loadSheet(function (sheet){
  o.sheet = sheet;
});
```

You can pass any extra parameters to `loadSheet` as required.

Can make this nicer:

- Use promises, but adds potentially unneeded complexity.
- Pass `(err, sheet)` to `cb` to allow errors to propagate forward.
- Add a `setTimeout` to kill the loading of the sheet if it times out, depending if needed.

### Decoupling and encapsulation

There are 3 options for how 2 objects can interact.

1. `A` knows about `B`
2. `B` knows about `A`
3. Make another thing `C`, that knows about `A` and `B`

If you want `A` and `B` to be 100% decoupled. Then making a function that encapsulates the `A` and `B` is the only option.

Comment: I am troubled that `loadSheet` function has access to `obj`. I want functions that handle stylesheet’s loading to only return the resulting `sheet`, but not to “know” anything about where it will be assigned.

Comment: @Displayname: Isn't that exactly what my answer demonstrates?

Comment: NO..! XD... but kind of yes... i think no matter how you do it. `Promise` or `cb` you still have to encapsulate `o.sheet` in a function.

Comment: @PhilPoore: That was directed at Displayname, not you, responding to his comment about decouplnig above. Sorry for any confusion.